# TensorFlow: convert tf.Dataset to tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I want to generate windows of the range of 10:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
dataset = dataset.window(5, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
```

and would like to train my model on this dataset.

To do so, those windows have to be converted to tensors. But the datatype of these windows cannot be converted via `tf.convert_to_tensor` to a tensor. It is possible to do `tf.convert_to_tensor(list(window))` but this is quite inefficient.

Does anyone know how to convert a `tf.VariantDataset` efficiently to a `tf.Tensor`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You generally do not convert datasets to tensors as such, you iterate datasets and they give you tensors in those iterations. You want to one of those windows? Or you want to get a tensor containing all the windows?

Comment: @jdehesa the latter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a tensor of sliding windows, doing it through a dataset is not really the best way, is far less efficient and flexible. I don't think there is a proper operation for that, but there are two similar ones for 2D and 3D arrays, [`tf.image.extract_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/extract_patches) and [`tf.extract_volume_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_volume_patches). You can reshape your 1D data to use them:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.range(10)
win_size = 5
stride = 1
# Option 1
a_win = tf.image.extract_patches(tf.reshape(a, [1, -1, 1, 1]),
                                 sizes=[1, win_size, 1, 1],
                                 strides=[1, stride, 1, 1],
                                 rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                 padding='VALID')[0, :, 0]
# Option 2
a_win = tf.extract_volume_patches(tf.reshape(a, [1, -1, 1, 1, 1]),
                                  ksizes=[1, win_size, 1, 1, 1],
                                  strides=[1, stride, 1, 1, 1],
                                  padding='VALID')[0, :, 0, 0]
# Print result
print(a_win.numpy())
# [[0 1 2 3 4]
#  [1 2 3 4 5]
#  [2 3 4 5 6]
#  [3 4 5 6 7]
#  [4 5 6 7 8]
#  [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!